# React Chrome vs Firefox Navigation is not defined

Tags: reactjs, django, firefox, navigation

My site works fine on Chrome but goes blank on Firefox.

The problematic line is:

```
// Setting default values for the props of Navigation
Navigation.defaultProps = {};
```

The following is imported:

```
import styles from "components/Navigation/styles";
```

the error encountered is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Navigation is not defined
    js index.js:166
    js main.chunk.js:12080
    Webpack 27
index.js:166
    js index.js:166
    js main.chunk.js:12


ncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    4043 blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    r blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    8048 blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    r blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    8641 blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    r blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    <anonymous> blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    <anonymous> blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    <anonymous> blank line 122381 > injectedScript:2
    onload index.js:1
    be index.js:1
    me index.js:1
    te index.js:1
    promise callback*./node_modules/react-error-overlay/lib/index.js/</te/< index.js:1
    ce index.js:1
    t index.js:1
    o index.js:1
    ce index.js:1
    ge index.js:1
    js webpackHotDevClient.js:45
    Webpack 7
```

What am I missing that causes Chrome to work but Edge/Safari to fail.